# Prometheus - Direct Instrumentation vs Custom Collector

Tags: go, prometheus

I am not able to understand when to have a custom collector vs when not to. Can someone explain? Do I need a custom collector if I do not have a use-case of proxying metrics from other systems?

In what ways these options affects the performance of capturing metrics?